# How to fix Postman data different than fetched data

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, postman

I'm setting up a file so that I can seed my database. I want to fetch data from an external api and then map over the returned data and seed accordingly. I am running the file with a script I created that's just node . When I fetch data from the API both on my client and in Postman I get the expected results. However, when I try it with the seed file I am creating, the data looks exactly like what I should be getting except for the response.data is a string now and not an object. I can't seem to figure out why that would be.

data returned from the seed file

```js
data: '﻿{"columns":[{"code":"Region","text":"region","type":"d"},{"code":"Kon","text":"sex","type":"d"},{"code":"Tid","text":"year","type":"t"},{"code":"BE0101N1","text":"Population","comment":"The ' +
    'tables show the conditions on December 31st for each respective year ' +
    'according to administrative subdivisions of January 1st of the ' +
    'following year\\r\\n","type":"c"},{"code":"BE0101N2","text":"Population ' +
    'growth","comment":"Population growth is defined as the difference ' +
    'between the population at the beginning of the year and at the end of ' +
    'the ' +
    'year.\\r\\n","type":"c"}],"comments":[],"data":[{"key":["0117","1","2013"],"values":["20389","154"]},{"key":["0117","2","2013"],"values":["20106","72"]}]}'
```

data returned to postman

```js
{
    "columns": [
        {
            "code": "Kon",
            "text": "sex",
            "type": "d"
        },
        {
            "code": "Tid",
            "text": "year",
            "type": "t"
        },
        {
            "code": "BE0101N1",
            "text": "Population",
            "comment": "The tables show the conditions on December 31st for each respective year according to administrative subdivisions of January 1st of the following year\r\n",
            "type": "c"
        },
        {
            "code": "BE0101N2",
            "text": "Population growth",
            "comment": "Population growth is defined as the difference between the population at the beginning of the year and at the end of the year.\r\n",
            "type": "c"
        }
    ],
    "comments": [],
    "data": [
        {
            "key": [
                "1",
                "2013"
            ],
            "values": [
                "4814357",
                "48452"
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": [
                "2",
                "2013"
            ],
            "values": [
                "4830507",
                "40519"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Click on `Raw` right under `Body` and you should get what you need

Comment: @Rikin postman is sending the data back correctly, it's the axios call in my seed file that is sending the data back as a string